# SSIS 2012 Execute Package from SSISDB on 64 bit system

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

I am having trouble executing my package because I get the following error:

> The requested OLE DB provider Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 is not
>   registered. If the 64-bit driver is not installed run the package in
>   32-bit mode.

I looked around and from what I understand this is because excel or access connections need to be made in 32 bit mode with 32 bit drivers.  I know that within my designer I can go to properties and change the Run64BitRuntime option to false.  That is not the problem. It runs fine in my designer.  My issue is how do I specify this when running my package from SSISDB?

Comment: Do you mean running it from SQL Job Agent via SSISDB? There is a setting under a step where you can enable Run in 32bit mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If setting Run64BitRunTime works in SSIS Designer and your having a problem when executing your ssis-package from SSISDB via SQL Job Agent.

You should set a check mark in 32-Bit runtime under step properties.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

if you execute your package via SSISDB stored procedures, the `catalog.create_execution` SP has a `@use32bitruntime` parameter that will run your package in 32-bit mode directly from SSISDB.

```
--@use32bitruntime=True will enable 32-bit mode
Declare @execution_id bigint
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[create_execution] @package_name=N'32BitPackage.dtsx', @execution_id=@execution_id OUTPUT, 
@folder_name=N'Test Folder', @project_name=N'Test Project', @use32bitruntime=True, @reference_id=Null
Select @execution_id

--parameter/logging configuration
DECLARE @var0 smallint = 1
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[set_execution_parameter_value] @execution_id,  
@object_type=50, @parameter_name=N'LOGGING_LEVEL', @parameter_value=@var0

--run package
EXEC [SSISDB].[catalog].[start_execution] @execution_id

GO
```